# When using the DDay ical library, How do you indicate busy versus free versus out office?

Tags: c#, icalendar, dday

I am using the [DDal ical library](http://www.ddaysoftware.com/Pages/Projects/DDay.iCal/) which works great but i just realized that i wanted to see how to indicate an event as out of office versus busy (so it shows up different when loaded in microsoft outlook

I see the property [listed on this microsoft site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee219533%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) called:

- X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS
- PidLidBusyStatus

Is this possible to set this from within DDay ical library as i don't see anything in the documentation?

Comment: Do you feel that my post does not answer you question sufficiently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have **Free/Busy Component** on your mind  described in [RFC 2445](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2445.txt), then it is not implemented yet based on the [DDay.iCal Compliance with RFC 2445](http://www.ddaysoftware.com/Pages/Projects/DDay.iCal/Compliance.aspx) list.

Comment: is this what indicate as out of office versus busy?

Comment: I went throught all the code and unless the functionality you seek is named so that it hides in something else (which I don't think so), than yes ... should you come across a different statement, do tell me, please

Answer (score 1):

([Don't use dday.ical](http://rianjs.net/2016/07/dday-ical-is-now-ical-net); use [ical.net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ical.Net). It contains many performance enhancements and bugfixes.)

Anything prefixed with `X-` means it's vendor-specific. There is no standard way to say "out of office" vs "busy". I believe Outlook also has a notion of "tentative" that also goes into that field.

The icalendar [spec supports](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.2.9) four basic statuses: "FREE", "BUSY", "BUSY-UNAVAILABLE", "BUSY-TENTATIVE". These are all valid options for the `VFREEBUSY` component. The spec intends for the VFREEBUSY with its subheading FREEBUSY components to essentially communicate free-busy information for people trying to plan a meeting. Outlook has its scheduling assistant feature; it may will be using VFREEBUSY information to show its timelines.

So that's not really what you're looking for.

The spec does have a notion of [categories](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.1.2), and one of the examples is "NOT IN OFFICE":

> Some possible English values for "CATEGORIES" property include:
> "ANNIVERSARY", "APPOINTMENT", "BUSINESS", "EDUCATION", "HOLIDAY",
> "MEETING", "MISCELLANEOUS", "NON-WORKING HOURS", "NOT IN OFFICE",
> "PERSONAL", "PHONE CALL", "SICK DAY", "SPECIAL OCCASION", "TRAVEL",
> "VACATION".  Categories can be specified in any registered language.

Neither of these options is great, and is, IMO, yet another place the spec falls short. You almost want a BUSY-OUT-OF-OFFICE status that can be specified in a `VFREEBUSY` manifest, but the spec doesn't have it, and neither does ical.net (or dday.ical before it).

To that end, you're better off adding the `X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS` property to the event manually, if Outlook is the thing consuming the serialized output:

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
var later = now.AddHours(1);

var e = new Event
{
    DtStart = new CalDateTime(now),
    DtEnd = new CalDateTime(later),
};
e.AddProperty("X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS", "OOF"); // I think "OOF" is right per the MS documentation

var calendar = new Calendar();
calendar.Events.Add(e);

var serializer = new CalendarSerializer(new SerializationContext());
var icalString = serializer.SerializeToString(calendar);
Console.WriteLine(icalString);
```

That'll generate this:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//github.com/rianjs/ical.net//NONSGML ical.net 2.1//EN
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTEND:20160827T162931
DTSTAMP:20160827T192931Z
DTSTART:20160827T152931
SEQUENCE:0
UID:fea526df-7f40-4585-a9de-8d422e43eebe
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:OOF
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Comment: Does OOF set it as Our of Office in Outlook 2016?

Comment: Also, is there a way to set it to private?